# How to get dummy variables from "first name"

Tags: bigdata, feature-extraction, categorical-data, pyspark, dummy-variables

I intend to predict the age of customers using some features. There are some categorical features that I need to convert to dummy variables before the modelling stage.

Since the datasets are so big (millions of rows) when I used StringIndexer in pyspark to get dummies from first names, I got the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 25.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 25.0 (TID 399, 10.139.64.28, executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(StringIndexerModel$$Lambda$6517/699548305: (string) =&gt; double)
```

Can you suggest any better approach to convert the first names to dummy variables?

Comment: I don't know spark and I have no idea what this error means, but this is certainly a case where discarding the least frequent names first is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are writing a user defined function to parse the data `Failed to execute user defined function(StringIndexerModel$$Lambda$6517/699548305: (string)`. It is better to use the built-in Spark functions (which are more scalable).

After you parse the string, use [OneHotEncoderEstimator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-features.html#onehotencoderestimator) to generate the dummy variables.